# Use text input by a user to reference/call the data in a variable VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to reference a variable by what the user enters:
For example:

```
Dim str1 As String = "sherrifs"
Dim str2 As String = "cowboys"
Dim str3 As String = "aliens"
Dim strUserInput As String
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a variable name: ")
    strUserInput = Console.ReadLine()
```

If the user enters str1 then the output should be sherrifs etc..
How would I go about doing this in vb.net?
Thanks

Comment: The usual way, in a console mode app, to give a user a choice between 3 options is to let him enter a number between 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to keep your items in a `Dictionary<string, string>` object. 
Keep key as variableName, value as variableValue.

```
Dictionary<string, string> variableList = new Dictionary<string, string>()
variableList.Add("str1", "sherrifs")
variableList.Add("str2", "cowboys")
variableList.Add("str3", "aliens")

Dim strUserInput As String
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a variable name: ")
strUserInput = Console.ReadLine()

If variableList.ContainsKey(strUserInput) Then
   Console.WriteLine(variableList(strUserInput))
Else
   Console.WriteLine ("No luck")
```

Comment: Welcome @CameronWickes, if it helped you can upvote and [mark as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Accepted answers will help others also.